# Some issues with fontspec using R Markdown

Tags: fontspec, rmarkdown

I use an R Markdown file to write articles and to be able to output both Latex and Word documents. I use a csl file for my references and my mainfont is set with fontspec. When I compile my file, I observe that dashes between pages numbers are not recognized in my bibliography section. For instance, as you can see on the picture below, instead of having 77-93, I have a blank space between the two numbers: 77 93.

[image]

Three things I saw too:

1. I don't observe the same result using my bib file.
2. When I compile without using fontspec, I have no issues with it.
3. When I convert my file into a Word document, no issue at all.

Do you know why ? (No MWE since I think it's a "technical" question, but if you need one, feel free to tell me.)

Comment: Sorry but do you really expect us to know why an unknown font in an unknown code doesn't show an unknown char (hyphen? en-dash? something else?)? check the log-file for clues or make an example that we can test - one that doesn't require to setup a R-markdown workflow first.

Comment: I suspect something like an incompatibility between fontspec and csl, but I'm not an expert. It's almost a "theoretical" question, purely technical. Moreover, I have no issue when I compile my file with a Latex tool and using my usual font Janson Text LT Std. That's the reason why I posted my question here without R Markdown MWE, thinking — mistakenly? — that someone could have met a similar issue.